# Javascript: Set ID to a child existing table

Tags: javascript, html-table, identifier

I need to assign/set a unique ID to child tables per Javascript. The main parent table has an ID but the child tables and further child tables within child tables don't.

How can I set an ID to the 1st child and second child tables "on page load"?

```
<table id="main parent table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are the tables created dynamically?

Comment: Define "on page load": if those tables are in the initial HTML document, then add IDs before serve it. If they are generated, that function should generate them with a valid id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking to do something like this [(fiddle here)](http://gmail.com) :

```
$('table').each(function(eq, el) {
    el = $(el);
    if(typeof(el.attr('id')) === "undefined") {
        el.attr('id', 'table-' + eq);
    }
});
```

You check every table on site and if it has no id, you assign id of "table-" to each one in the tree.

Answer (score -1):

Use Jquery loop on Top table `children` loop on inner table. `find` and `addClass` on them.